# Issue with 100% high Mapbox map when rendering with React

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am rendering a map using Mapboxgl, Bootstrap 4 and React.

I need the map to take 100% of the height of the page and to display in the first column of a two column grid.

However, when using React, the width of the map extends over to 100% of the width of the row - overlapping underneath the 2nd column.

The best thing would be to check my examples on jsfidle to understand what I mean.

Map **correctly** showing (when using pure HTML and no React)
https://jsfiddle.net/apphancer/jhxy5c63/

Map showing width **issue** (when using React)
https://jsfiddle.net/apphancer/9g71ovn6/

In order to have the 100% height working I am using this CSS:

```
.map-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I suspect this might have something to do with how the map gets rendered with React as the problem does not happen when using the pure HTML solution.

Is anyone able to point in the right direction?

HTML

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#app, .row, .col-9 {
    height: 100%;
}

.col-3 {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.map-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4M29iazA2Z2gycXA4N2pmbDZmangifQ.-g_vE53SD2WrJ6tFX7QHmA';

class Application extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map', // container id
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9', // stylesheet location
            center: [13.392, 52.523], // starting position [lng, lat]
            zoom: 9 // starting zoom
        });
        map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
        map.resize(); // tried with this to see if it would help
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="row no-gutters">
                <div className="col-9">
                    <div className="map-wrapper">
                        <div ref={el => this.mapContainer = el} id="map"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-3">
                    2 of 2
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use position fixed with 100% width in wrapper, it will cover all width. But if you set position to relative, it will cover just remaining width.

```
.map-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This worked in your react-jsfiddle. Please try.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using position `fixed` in your project you can cover whole area so for that you have 2 solution

**1st solution**

give `75%` width to the `#map` so it will behave like `col-9` and no need to give `position: absolute;`

```
#map {
    width: 75%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**2nd Solution**

give it relative position to the parent of your element so it cant leave it area, for that you can change `position: fixed` to `position: relative`

```
.map-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

both solution is good solution but i prefer **2nd solution**, from my side.

Answer (score 0):

const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
width: '100%',
height: 'calc(100vh - 162px)', // 162px is size height of all elements on top of map
latitude: 0,
longitude: 0,
zoom: 12,
bearing: 0,
pitch: 0,
transitionDuration: 2000,
transitionInterpolator: new FlyToInterpolator(),
});

Answer (score 0):

I migrated to **React 18**, and updated a bunch of dependencies, included the map library.

The only thing that resolved my problem was this. It has a tic, when the map resizes, but it's a start.

```
useEffect(() => {
    map.on("load", () => map.resize());
}, [])
```